# Sending data to Google Spreadsheet via Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm having problems sending data to a Google Spreadsheet via Ajax.

I followed this guide to achieve this: https://medium.com/@dmccoy/how-to-submit-an-html-form-to-google-sheets-without-google-forms-b833952cc175

My own code looks as simple as this:

```
var data = {"user": "bar"};
var url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycby6BzLifopR36ZBJ2WqDMNsndCYUpHihSOfhomfSRZXcdetvOA/exec';

$('.my-button').on('click', function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data: data
    }).done(
        function (__e) {
            console.log('Remote sheet updated!', __e);
        }
    ).fail(function (__e) {
        console.log('Remote sheet update failed', __e);
    });
});
```

This is what my spreadsheet looks like:

[image]

This is the code from the tutorial that goes into the Google scripteditor.

```
function doGet(e){
  return handleResponse(e);
}

//  Enter sheet name where data is to be written below
        var SHEET_NAME = "DATA";

var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); // new property service

function handleResponse(e) {
  // shortly after my original solution Google announced the LockService[1]
  // this prevents concurrent access overwritting data
  // [1] http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/concurrency-and-google-apps-script.html
  // we want a public lock, one that locks for all invocations
  var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
  lock.waitLock(30000);  // wait 30 seconds before conceding defeat.

  try {
    // next set where we write the data - you could write to multiple/alternate destinations
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);

    // we'll assume header is in row 1 but you can override with header_row in GET/POST data
    var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; // get next row
    var row = []; 
    // loop through the header columns
    for (i in headers){
      if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){ // special case if you include a 'Timestamp' column
        row.push(new Date());
      } else { // else use header name to get data
        row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]);
      }
    }
    // more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
    // return json success results
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": nextRow}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch(e){
    // if error return this
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": e}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } finally { //release lock
    lock.releaseLock();
  }
}

function setup() {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("key", doc.getId());
}
```

In the code provided by the author of the tutorial all I did is change the sheet name in line 9 to "DATA"

```
//  Enter sheet name where data is to be written below
    var SHEET_NAME = "DATA";
```

...which is the name of the sheet.

[image]

The problem is now, when I click "my-button", it gets send successfully, but returns an error object. The error doesn't contain any additional information though. It seems to go into the "catch" section of the Google script, but doesn't inform me of what exactly went wrong. Now I don't even know how to debug this, let alone understand, what went wrong.

I already tried all kinds of weird things like using `JSON.stringify`, none of that helped. It should work like this anyway, so I have no idea what's the problem here.

[image]

Comment: Your question should include all the necessary information, even if this information can be found in a referenced link. Could you please provide all the code you're using, including the HTML and the script project?

Comment: Ok, I added it. As of now I'm not using any HTML, because I'm just trying to get this to work with a dummy JSON object.

Comment: Just one question - did you redeploy the script after the change? You seem to request the `/exec` endpoint, which serves a snapshot of your code, most likely the one before the change, but the sheet name is now different. Add a `console.log` to the catch block of the server-side code to be sure (it will log to stackdriver). You should really use `/dev` endpoint while in development, versions tend to clutter pretty quickly

Comment: I would greatly simplify my doGet(e)  until I confirm that the communications are working.

Comment: I tried to reproduce this, and could get the spreadsheet updated successfully. Did you set the `key` property (running the function `setup`)? Otherwise, the script will not be able to retrieve the spreadsheet in this line: `var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));`. I think that's possibly the reason for this problem. Could you please check that? (run `setup` to set the `key` property and check if you still experience this behaviour).